# Предотвратить повторное сохранение

Tags: php

Всем привет, есть админка и редактирование новости в котором принимает участие большое количество человек.

Когда человек заходит в новость и делает что-то и потом заходит еще один человек и вносит изменения и сохраняет, то у первого человека пропадут его изменения при сохранении новости.

Щас у меня есть скрытое поле с датой с последним обновлением новости:

```
<input type="hidden" value="$item->updated_at">
```

updated_at - это колонка обновления новости (дата) timestamp

В контроллере у меня проверка:

```
 if($item->updated_at != $this->request->get('updated_at'))
                exit('please enter on other time here');
```

Но это не работает,  если страница обновляется, ибо если обновляется страница, то скрытое поле обновляется.

Как я могу вообще запретить входить в новость, если в ней уже кто-то сидит?

Comment: Если скрытое поле обновляется, то обновляются и другие поля обновляются и у него значит актуальная новость. или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Ок, а чтобы в новость нельзя было зайти?)) Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Можно, придется сильно постараться. Но это уже другой вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы заблокировать редактирование элемента, можно добавить ему свойство blocked. Либо создать отдельную таблицу с блокировками, где будет имя таблицы, id, время и кто заблокировал.

Важно сделать надежный функционал автоматического снятия блокировки, чтобы она не зависла. К примеру, в открытой вкладке нужно периодически пинговать и обновлять время блокировки, а по cron-у снимать блокировки у элементов, у которых вышел таймаут.

Также нужно реализовать возможность съема блокировки пользователем. К примеру, если человек забыл закрыть вкладку. Такая функция есть в CMS-ках, например WordPress.

Comment: а чего минусуете то? есть другие идеи что-ли, дак высказывайте